# How to enlarge an area that stays with the texts of an axis? Google charts

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization

I have doubts about the spacing of data that is horizontal, when the text is a little larger, it is reducing with three points, my goal is to generate pdf, it must show the full value.[1](https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/problema.rtVbPj)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            google.load("visualization", "1.1", {
                packages: ["corechart"],
                callback: 'grafico'
            });
        }

        function grafico() {

             var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Coding', 11],
                ['Eat', 1],
                ['Commute', 2],
                ['Looking for code Problems', 4],
                ['Sleep', 6]
            ]);

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dados);

            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

                view.setColumns([0,
                    1, {
                        type: 'string',
                        role: 'annotation',
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        calc: 'stringify'
                    },
                    2, {
                        type: 'string',
                        role: 'annotation',
                        sourceColumn: 2,
                        calc: 'stringify'
                    }

                ]);

                var options = {
                    title: 'Cronograma',
                    vAxis: {title: 'Percentual'},
                    hAxis: {
                        title: 'Grupo',
                        // slantedText: true,
                        // slantedTextAngle: 90,
                        textStyle: {
                            fontSize: 10,
                        },
                    },
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));

            chart.draw(view, options);
        }
    </script>
```

```
<div id="grafico" class="grafico"></div>
```

You cannot enlarge the horizontal text area so that the text is not minified.

Comment: Example:
https://ap.imagensbrasil.org/image/problema.rtVbPj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enlarge the area with the *horizontal text*,
use config option...

```
chartArea: {
  bottom: 200
},
```

note: as a result, you may also have to increase the `top` & `left`.

```
chartArea: {
  bottom: 300,
  left: 150,
  top: 36
},
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Name', 'Previsto', 'Executado'],
     ['OBRA DE REQUALIFICACAO DA MORE TEXT', 22, 22],
     ['DEMOLICOES RETIRADAS E REQUEST MORE TEST', 4, 0],
     ['DRENA', 0, 0]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }, 2, {
    calc: 'stringify',
    sourceColumn: 2,
    type: 'string',
    role: 'annotation'
  }]);

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 300,
      left: 200,
      top: 36
    },
    height: 600,
    title : 'Cronograma',
    vAxis: {title: 'Percentual'},
    hAxis: {
      slantedText: true,
      title: 'Grupo'
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);

  chart.draw(view, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

as a last resort, you could reduce the font size...

```
hAxis: {
  slantedText: true,
  title: 'Grupo',
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 8
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much WhiteHat, I was having a hard time understanding how to best solve this situation.